# For loop in Django templates - Biggest to smallest and split

Tags: django

How can I with a for loop in Django templates use the "tag" from biggest to smallest in list order?

I also want to split after 20 entries. So that tag after 20 is not displayed. How could this be done?

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    <p>TAG: {{ tag }} - {{ tag.item_count }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If this is for paging through large amounts of data, the view should be handing the correct data to the template via the context. I.e. `tags[0:20]` then `tags[20:40]`, etc. Obviously, the view can do arbitrary sorting / grouping of the data before rendering the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple options-

**Sort the tags queryset with `order_by`**

In your view, before including tags in your context_data:

```
tags = YourTagModel.objects.filter(...).order_by('-item_count')[:20] # greatest number of item_count first; remove the - to sort smallest first)
```

In addition to sorting, `[:20]` slices the queryset to only return the first 20 matches in the sorted set. If you need users to browse through those, [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/) is the generally accepted method.

**Custom template tag**

Create a directory `templatetags` in your app dir. Add an empty `__init__.py` file to the dir. Create a `my_tags.py` file in the dir.

from django import template
register = template.Library()

```
@register.filter
def sort_by(queryset, field):
    return queryset.order_by(field)

@register.filter
def reverse_sort_by(queryset, field):
    return queryset.order_by("-%s" % (field,))
```

Then in your template:

```
   {% load my_tags %}

   {% for tag in tags|sort_by:"item_count"|slice:":20" %}
       <p>TAG: {{ tag }} - {{ tag.item_count }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
```

Hint - Go with option 1  ;)

Comment: Perfect Ian. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Question one depends on what your `tags` contains. (list, queryset etc).
But the [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag could be a starting point.

For question 2 - use [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% for tag in tags|slice:":20" %}
    <p>TAG: {{ tag }} - {{ tag.item_count }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```